# Web API controller doesn't set Guid correctly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

Model:

```cs
public class SomethingDto
{
    [Required]
    public JToken Data { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Something2 Something { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SomethingId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("something/process")]
public async Task<SomethingDto> Apply(SomethingDto request)
{
    // request.SomethingId is "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" but should be "3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6"
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "bla": "hkjkn",
    "blabla": "kjnkjnjk",
    "blablabla": "illmlkml"
  },
  "Something": {
    "Data": "blablabla"
  },
  "SomethingId": "3FA85F64-5717-4562-B3FC-2C963F66AFA6"
}
```

When I make a request to the controller, every property is set correctly except Guid SomethingId. Why?

```cs
var json = File.ReadAllText("request.json");
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await HttpClient.PostAsync($"/something/process", data);
```

Comment: Hi, just want to clarify. Is the API Controller using (ASP).Net framework or (ASP).Net Core framework?

Comment: @YongShun Hi, ASP.NET Core 6

Comment: What json library have you used? Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Something wrong with JToken, how do you pass them withing JSON? Are you sure that you are using correct type?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the file is read successfully and return a valid json.

Seems you are passing the whole object through the request body, you need to apply `[FromBody]` attribute in the controller.

> Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("something/process")]
public async Task<SomethingDto> Apply([FromBody]SomethingDto request)
{
    ...
}
```

While your `SomethingDto` class should be as:

```cs
public class SomethingDto
{
    [Required]
    public Data Data { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Something2 Something { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid SomethingId { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string bla { get; set; }
    public string blabla { get; set; }
    public string blablabla { get; set; }
}

public class Something2
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

> Debugging & Output

*Sending request via Postman*

[image]

*Result for API receiving data*

[image]

Comment: Is it always require to put a FromBody attribute?

Comment: Hi, for my best practice I will place `[FromBody]` attribute when the controller API method is expected to receive the object from the request body. While just now I try to reproduce without `[FromBody]` in my local side, the received object was with all the properties are empty.

Comment: Very interesting, I was thinking that FromBody is default attribute for complext type. Moreover, I reproduce this in my dev environment and everythings work correctly.

Comment: Thank you. But problem was that my json was incorrect. Someone changed newtonjson options in Startup.cs to use snake casing. In json file I changed it to "something_id" and it worked.